# Is it possible to insert Admob ads into Cordova pages "inline"?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-admob

I have made a lot of search but can now find a way to display Admob ads the way I want (see pic).[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is discouraged, read https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287.

You can see positioning instructions here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/setOptions#options

```
admob.createBannerView({
    publisherId: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
    bannerAtTop: true // or false
});
```

**EDIT**

You could have an opportunity if you summit your app to custom search ads and get approved: https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/docs/android/

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible to insert ads like this because they would have to go into the DOM (possibly using new Native Ads). You can insert at the top or bottom of the screen using this plugin https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-plugin-admob-simple but that is all.